# Querying 3 tables by comparing column values and with no primary or foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, join

I have 3 tables A, B and C. 
Table A contains product details with no price column in it.
Table B and C contains product details with price column in it.

The product in Table A may or may not be present in table B or C.

I want to get the minimum price of the product of Table A if it is present in table B or C and select the mininum price from B or C

Lets say Table A has Property1 , Property2 and Property3

---

Table B has Price,Property1 , Property2 and Property3

---

Table C has Price,Property1 , Property2 and Property3

Get the minimun price for Product from Table B or C whichever price is  where A.properties  matches with properties of B and C

How do I query this.

Comment: posting sample data will be much more helpful for all

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT big.prop1, big.prop2, MIN(big.price)
FROM (
    SELECT a.prop1, a.prop2, b.price
    FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.prop1 = b.prop1 AND a.prop2 = b.prop2

    UNION

    SELECT a.prop1, a.prop2, c.price
    FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableC c ON a.prop1 = c.prop1 AND a.prop2 = c.prop2
) AS Big
GROUP BY big.prop1, big.prop2
```

But, that is bad practice, you need foreign key for each combination og properties to join tables.

Comment: this will return records from a even if they don't exist in b or c.  see my solution below which doesn't return records from a if it doesn't exist in either a or b.

Comment: @JoshGilfillan-Thanks , I wanted to check one more thing if I can put like condition here. For a.property1 is "Samsung Mobile" and c.prop1 is "Samsung" so is there a way I can put a like here. a.prop1 like c.prop1.

Comment: @John you can put it before `GROUP BY` or add `WHERE` after aech `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You could combine data from table b and c with `union all`, then use an `inner join` to table a, combined with a `min()` and `group by` to get the minimum price.

```
select a.property1, a.property2, a.property3, min(x.price) as min_price
from table_a a

-- join to combined data from table b and table c
inner join (
  select price, property1, property2, property3
  from table_b 
  union all
  select price, property1, property2, property3
  from table_c
) x
-- join on properties
on a.property1= x.property1
and a.property2= x.property2
and a.property3= x.property3
)
group by a.property1, a.property2, a.property3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #a (Property varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #A VALUES ('X')
INSERT INTO #A VALUES ('D')
INSERT INTO #A VALUES ('I')

create table #b (price int,Property varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #B VALUES (10,'X')
INSERT INTO #B VALUES (11,'D')
INSERT INTO #B VALUES (12,'I')

create table #c (price int ,Property varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #C VALUES (8,'X')
INSERT INTO #C VALUES (9,'D')
INSERT INTO #C VALUES (7,'I')

SELECT B.PROPERTY,CASE WHEN MIN(B.PRICE) <  MIN (C.PRICE) THEN B.PRICE ELSE C.PRICE END AS PRICE
FROM #B B INNER JOIN #C C ON B.Property=C.Property INNER JOIN #A A ON B.Property=A.Property
GROUP BY B.PRICE,C.PRICE,B.PROPERTY

DROP TABLE #A
DROP TABLE #B
DROP TABLE #C
```

Comment: Copy paste this query and execute it in sql to understand the output.